# When to use scope resolution in javascript?

Tags: javascript

When I set the onload property I use

```
window.onload=initialize_page;
```

However,
when I use undefined, which I understand is a window property I simply use:

```
undefined
```

How do I know when to scope properties?

If I remove window from the first statement it works.  I guess I've seen both in code here on SO, but which way is best practice?

Comment: Everything in `window` is global, so `onload=initialize_page;` will actually work :-P

Comment: you can't go wrong with just being explicity...in C++ you have to either use a "using" statement or scopeexplicily...I th ink it's good to follow stricter languages as an example when possible.

Comment: I agree, adding `window.` is definitely safer, I just wanted to throw that out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to define a global variable, it's recommended to prefix `window.`, to prevent conflicts with local variables with the same name.

For example, Rocket (at the OP's comments) suggested to use `onload=initialize_page;` instead of `window.onload = ...`. This will fail in the following case:

```
function foo() {
    var onload = "on load";
    onload = initialise_page;
    // What? Let's check:
    alert(onload === window.onload); //false
}
foo();
```

*If you encounter a variable, and don't know whether it's a global variable or not, you can use the following code to determine it:*

```
alert( 'somevar' in window ); //If true, then in global scope. If false, then not
alert( somevar === window.somevar); // Risky. If somevar is not an object, this
                                    // comparison will also be true. Example:
                                    // var local = 1;window.local=1;
                                    // ^ They're equal by value
```

Comment: Also, it helps for clarity. `window.onload` makes sense grammatically (oh, when the window loads!), whereas `window.undefined` doesn't. Which is why you see `window.onblahblah` quite a lot.

Comment: Thanks...I'm good info..it seems I asked a preference question...for my preference I'm going to use it all the time just to be sure.